# Guardar valores e fazer uma comparação

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-activity

Estou com dificuldade em realizar uma logica para fazer comparação ou algo melhor que vocês possam me indicar.

Estou desenvolvendo um app que contém vários botões em formato de jogo da mega sena.

Preciso fazer com que caso uma bola ja esteja selecionada a cor mude para verde e caso receba um novo clique volte para a cor branca (Já estou conseguindo fazer isso ), porém preciso que caso ja tenha uma bola selecionada não deve ter a possibilidade dele selecionar uma nova.

[image: Imagem da tela de jogo]

Meu codigo:

```
public void buttonClick(View button){
    String tag = (String)button.getTag();
    int numeroInteiro = Integer.parseInt(tag);

    switch (numeroInteiro){
        default:
            if (ballsColor()){
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
            }else {
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
            }
            break;
    }
}

private boolean ballsColor(){
    if (count == 0){
        count++;
        return true;
    } else {
        count--;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Tem algum jeito de guardar um valor e nao ser sobrescrito em uma nova ação do botão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você pode fazer é adicionar uma `tag` para cada botão, criar uma variável `selectedTag` para armazenar a `tag` do botão selecionado e usar isso para fazer a lógica que precisa. Observe o código a seguir.

```java
private String selectedTag = null;

public void buttonClick(View button){
    String tag = (String) button.getTag();

    if(this.selectedTag == null){
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
        selectedTag = tag;
    }else if(this.selectedTag.equals(tag)){
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball);
        selectedTag = null;
    }
}
```

> Estou considerando que o método `buttonClick` será usado para tratar o evento de `click` de todos os botões.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Deu certinho, muito obrigado!!